# Вывести красиво строки JSON

Tags: php, json

Есть масив

```
 $row = array('Data',array('data' => '12345'), 'Time',array('time' => '12345'));
 $rez = json_encode($row);
 echo $rez;
```

Как красиво вывести данные из json в php?
На пример:

```
  {
      "Data"  :  {"data":"12345"},
      "Time" :  {"time":"12345"}
  }
```

Comment: начните с валидного описания исходного массива.

Answer (score 4):

Попробуй так

```
$rez = json_encode($row, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: если PHP выше 5.4 )

Answer (score 1):

```
 $row = array('Data',array('data':'12345'), 'Time',array('time':'12345'));
 $rez = json_encode($row);
 echo '<pre>';
       echo $rez;
 echo '</pre>';
```

тег `<pre>` вам в помощь http://htmlbook.ru/html/pre

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно вывести на страницу, где уже есть HTML:

```
<?php
  $j = file_get_contents( __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'data.json' ); 
  $data = json_encode(json_decode($j), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
  echo '<pre>' . $data . '</pre>';
?>
```